# Ошибка при работе mitmAP

Tags: linux, debian, kali-linux

После ответов на вопросы, запускается ТД и постоянно появляется такое сообщение:

```
Restarting tail in 1 sec... (press 'CTRL + C' again to stop)
tail: невозможно открыть '/home/kali/mitmAP/logs/mitmap-sslstrip.log' для чтения: Нет такого файла или каталога
tail: больше нет файлов
```

И так каждую секунду. ТД существует, даже можно подключиться к ней, но в консоли кроме этого сообщения ничего нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему переустановкой OpenSSL командой:

pip3 install pyOpenSSL

И созданием файла mitmap-sslstrip.log командой:

touch  /home/kali/mitmAP/logs/mitmap-sslstrip